# subquery with count

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

Let's say I have following table "*geo*"

| Country | Province | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Netherlands | Drenthe | Assen |
| Netherlands | Drenthe | Coevorden |
| Netherlands | Drenthe | Emmen |
| Netherlands | Flevoland | Biddinghuizen |
| Netherlands | Flevoland | Biddinghuizen |
| Netherlands | Flevoland | Biddinghuizen |
| Netherlands | Flevoland | Biddinghuizen |
| Belgium | Antwerp | Antwerp |
| Belgium | Antwerp | Aartselaar |
| Belgium | Antwerp | Boom |

I would like to query following output (return distinct county + province + number of times country is seeing in the table)

| Country | Province | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Netherlands | Drenthe | 2 |
| Netherlands | Flevoland | 2 |
| Belgium | Antwerp | 1 |

so I can make it in 2 steps

1. query country and province

```
select country, province from geo
group by country, province
```

but I don't understand how can I go to desire result from step 1

is it possible to make it in one step?

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: What DBMS are you currently using?

Comment: I use sql server, thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One generalized option is using the `DISTINCT` operator to aggregate on same provinces with respect to countries, then apply the COUNT window function with partial partitioning on countries.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Country, Province FROM tab
)
SELECT *, COUNT(Province) OVER(PARTITION BY Country) AS cnt
FROM cte
```

Here's a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9c62SH5o46QNNoa8emQrTZ/1) in MySQL, though this should be working on most DBMS'.

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer the simple (as per PM 77-1)

```
select country, province, count(*) As Kt
from geo
group by country, province
```